# How to use foreign key relationship in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have `School`, `Teachers` and `Qualifications` tables in my database. `Teacher` table refs `qualificationid` and `schoolid` in `Qualification` and `Schools` table.

I'm not using Entity Framework and I have DB-connection class to do CLUED operations.

In my `Teacher` class

```
public int TeacherID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string NIC { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set; }
public int Telephone { get; set; }

public Nullable<int> SchoolID { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> QualificationID { get; set; }

public virtual Qualifications Qualifications { get; set; }
public virtual Schools Schools { get; set; }
```

My `schools` class

```
public int SchoolID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int Telephone { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Teachers> Teachers { get; set; }
```

My `Qualification` class

```
public int QualificationID { get; set; }
public string Type { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Teachers> Teachers { get; set; }
```

My `DBConnection` class

```
public List<Teachers> getAllTeachers()
        {
            List<Teachers> teachersdata=new List<Teachers>();
            string connection = Connection.ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Teachers as T,Qualifications as Q,Schools as S  where S.SchoolID=T.SchoolID and T.QualificationID=Q.QualificationID";
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);
        while(dr.Read())
        {
            Teachers teacher = new Teachers();
            teacher.TeacherID = dr.GetInt32(0);
            teacher.Name = dr.GetString(1);
            teacher.NIC = dr.GetString(2);
            teacher.Address = dr.GetString(3);
            teacher.Telephone = dr.GetInt32(4);
            teacher.SchoolID = dr.GetInt32(5);
            teacher.QualificationID = dr.GetInt32(6);
            teacher.Qualifications.QualificationID = (Int32)dr["QualificationID"];
            teacher.Qualifications.Type =(string) dr["Type"];
            teacher.Schools.SchoolID = (Int32)dr["SchoolID"];
            teacher.Schools.Name = (string)dr["Name"];
            teacher.Schools.Telephone = (Int32)dr["Telephone"];
            teacher.Schools.Address = (string)dr["Address"];
            teachersdata.Add(teacher);
            }
            return teachersdata;
        }
```

in `teachersController`

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Teachers> allTeachers = _db.getAllTeachers();
            return View(allTeachers);
        }
```

at last in index.aspx i have

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<MyLayer.Teachers>>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
    </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TeacherID) %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name) %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NIC) %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address) %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Telephone) %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Schools.Name) %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Qualifications.Type) %>
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TeacherID) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NIC) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Telephone) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Schools.Name) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qualifications.Type) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) %> |
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) %> |
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run the project i got this error Object reference not set to an instance of an object in dbconnnection class  `teacher.Qualifications.QualificationID = (Int32)dr["QualificationID"];` .how can i fix this?

Comment: I think you should implement sql Join operator to include 2 related tables

Comment: I did but got this exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in DBconnection class teacher.Qualifications.QualificationID = (Int32)dr["QualificationID"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) program with this code

```
void Main()
{   
    Teachers teacher = new Teachers();
    teacher.TeacherID = 12;
    teacher.Name = "Jones";
    teacher.Qualifications.QualificationID = 7;
    teacher.Dump(); 
}
```

This is similar to the part you have in your loop. The problem is that `teacher.Qualifications` expects an instance of an object. But you did not create one. In your line `teacher.Qualifications.QualificationID` you are trying to assign a value to the non-static [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) `QualificationID`.

You could write

```
var qual = new Qualifications();
qual.QualificationID = 7;
teacher.Qualifications = qual;
```

Please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: thanks found a solution.... i add this to my DB-connection class List<Schools> schoolsdata = this.getAllSchools();
            
            List<Qualifications> qulificationData = this.getAllQualifications(); teacher.Schools = schoolsdata.Find(c => c.SchoolID == teacher.SchoolID);
                teacher.Qualifications = qulificationData.Find(c => c.QualificationID == teacher.QualificationID);

Comment: Was my answer helpfull in finding the cause for your errormessage `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"` ?
If this is the case would could you consider to accept it as an answer?